# Resharper indentation

Tags: resharper, code-formatting

How do I change the basic Resharper indentation options? I have noticed that Resharper's indentation settings differ from VS 2010's--VS uses four spaces for an indent, and it's hard to tell what Resharper uses--but the left margins on my code are jagged.

I'd like to reset Resharper to use the same settings as VS 2010, but I can't find the options.

Where can these be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay--I figured this one out: Resharper uses the Visual Studio tab settings when reformatting, so the inconsistency I am getting must have another source.

Answer (score 4):

Open ReSharper > Options > [Your language] > Formatting style > Other and try playing with options in sections called "Indentation" and "Other"

Comment: Thanks, but that simply sets the number of tab characters to insert.

Comment: This property page has a very useful setting "Indentation / Continuous line indent multiplier", which is exactly what I was looking for. I set this to 2 so that my line continuations are easily distinguishable from indentation for control flow, etc..